# Contar los json que vienen en un array SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Como puedo contar los item del array informacion

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
                "informacion":[
                                {"codigo":"RA1","Inactivo":1,"Impuesto":"RENTA 0,8%"},
                                {"codigo":"RA3","Inactivo":0,"Impuesto":"RENTA 0,9%"}                               
                              ]
             }'
```

Quisiera guardar la cantidad de JSON que trae el array informacion en una variable

```
DECLARE @count INT;
@count = ...
```

Comment: ¿Podrías contar los `},` más uno? ¿O quieres una validación más exacta? ¿Cuál versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: @Luis Cazares Gracias por la idea pero si debo tener algo más preciso, no se si podamos organizar el contenido de la variable json para poder contar sus elementos de manera más fácil

Answer (score 2):

El método más fácil para obtener la información que deseas es usando `OPENJSON()`. Sin embargo, este método solo está disponible en bases de datos con compatibilidad 130 en adelante, por lo que también requieres que el servidor esté usando SQL Server 2016 en adelante.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
                "informacion":[
                                {"codigo":"RA1","Inactivo":1,"Impuesto":"RENTA 0,8%"},
                                {"codigo":"RA3","Inactivo":0,"Impuesto":"RENTA 0,9%"}                               
                              ]
             }'

DECLARE @count INT;

SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.informacion');
```